# How to stop an asynchronous PowerShell scriptblock?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, runspace

I'm trying to have a Powershell script start a looping asynchronous script block and then do some "other stuff".  When the "other stuff" is complete at some unknown later time, I want to stop/kill the script block.

I see the [MS dev network info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.stopasync%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the `stopasych()` method, but can't figure out how to apply it in Powershell.

A simple example:

```
$runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$ps = [powershell]::create()
$ps.runspace = $runspace

[void]$ps.addscript({
   $beep = "`a"
   for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5000; $i++) {
      $beep
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
   }
})
$runspace.open()
$asyncObject = $ps.beginInvoke()

Copy-Item "c:\bigdata" "\\server\share"
```

That gets me started, but when the copying is done, I want to kill the beeping.  I can't reverse these (i.e. do the "copying" in the background) because there ends up with a delay until the condition, `$ps.InvocationStateInfo.state` is checked again.

Can anyone help?  BTW, I'd like to stick to PoSh v2.

Comment: `$ps.dispose()`?

Comment: @BenH Doh!  Boy, do I feel stupid.  I knew to use `.dispose()` when I was done, but I didn't realize it would stop the process too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just like `Invoke()` has an asynchronous Begin/End pair, so does `Stop()`.

You can wrap them like this to stop invocation:

```
$ps.EndStop($ps.BeginStop($null,$asyncObject))
```